# Java Weld null expressionFactory

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, cdi, weld

I use JBoss AS 7.1.1 + CDI (Weld) + JSF + Intellij IDEA.
I created project and downloaded files:

```
1. jsf-api.jar
2. jsf-impl.jar
3. jstl-1.1.0.jar
4. weld-servlet.jar
```

And everything is ok, until I start using Weld (create beans.xml and rename ManagedBeans to Named). After this, artifact stops deploying with error:

> "CONFIGURATION FAILED! WELD-001001 Cannot pass null expressionFactory".

Where is a mistake? Maybe there is incompatibility
of technologies versions? I have downloaded files with IDE Idea.

EDIT:

```
[2012-12-19 02:17:27,111] Artifact war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait... 14:17:27,314 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "war_exploded.war" 14:17:28,190 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Tomcat6InjectionProvider:org.apache.catalina.util.DefaultAnnotationProcessor' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider' 14:17:28,193 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Jetty6InjectionProvider:org.mortbay.jetty.plus.annotation.InjectionCollection' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider' 14:17:28,233 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment war_exploded.war 14:17:28,258 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: war_exploded.war 14:17:28,263 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS016008: Starting weld service for deployment war_exploded.war 14:17:28,334 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) The listener "com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored. 14:17:28,342 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-1) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1 (20120227-1401) for context '/war_exploded' 14:17:28,429 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-1) JSF1067: Resource /META-INF/faces-config.xml specified by the javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES configuration option cannot be found.  The resource will be ignored. 14:17:28,458 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-1) Critical error during deployment: : com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! WELD-001001 Cannot pass null expressionFactory     at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:376) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]   at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03] Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-001001 Cannot pass null expressionFactory     at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldExpressionFactory.<init>(WeldExpressionFactory.java:38) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]  at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.wrapExpressionFactory(BeanManagerImpl.java:995) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]     at org.jboss.as.weld.webtier.jsf.WeldApplication.getExpressionFactory(WeldApplication.java:91) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.jsf.WeldApplication.init(WeldApplication.java:79) [weld-servlet.jar:20120429-1045]    at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.jsf.WeldApplication.delegate(WeldApplication.java:87) [weld-servlet.jar:20120429-1045]    at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.jsf.ForwardingApplication.getActionListener(ForwardingApplication.java:168) [weld-servlet.jar:20120429-1045]  at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.addActionListener(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:459) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:290) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]     at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]     at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:222) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:361) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]   ... 9 more

14:17:28,487 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/war_exploded]] (MSC service thread 1-1) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! WELD-001001 Cannot pass null expressionFactory     at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]   at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03] Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! WELD-001001 Cannot pass null expressionFactory  at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:376) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]   ... 8 more Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-001001 Cannot pass null expressionFactory    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldExpressionFactory.<init>(WeldExpressionFactory.java:38) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]  at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.wrapExpressionFactory(BeanManagerImpl.java:995) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]     at org.jboss.as.weld.webtier.jsf.WeldApplication.getExpressionFactory(WeldApplication.java:91) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.jsf.WeldApplication.init(WeldApplication.java:79) [weld-servlet.jar:20120429-1045]    at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.jsf.WeldApplication.delegate(WeldApplication.java:87) [weld-servlet.jar:20120429-1045]    at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.jsf.ForwardingApplication.getActionListener(ForwardingApplication.java:168) [weld-servlet.jar:20120429-1045]  at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.addActionListener(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:459) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:290) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]     at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]     at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:222) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:361) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]   ... 9 more

14:17:28,519 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) Error listenerStart 14:17:28,520 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) Context [/war_exploded] startup failed due to previous errors 14:17:28,522 SEVERE [javax.faces] (MSC service thread 1-1) Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. Attempting to find backup. 14:17:28,524 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-1) Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory.   at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1008) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:343) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:131) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]     at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:328) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:3489) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:3999) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3917) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]   at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]

14:17:28,540 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./war_exploded: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./war_exploded: JBAS018040: Failed to start context    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95)     at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]

14:17:28,750 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 20) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "war_exploded.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./war_exploded" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./war_exploded: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}} 14:17:28,757 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment war_exploded.war 14:17:28,780 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment war_exploded.war in 31ms 14:17:28,782 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (management-handler-thread - 20) JBAS014774: Service status report JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./war_exploded: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./war_exploded: JBAS018040: Failed to start context

[2012-12-19 02:17:28,918] Artifact war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
```

Comment: post your stack trace message,cant understand anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of you're in using a container that certifies web profile or full profile (JBoss AS7 is both) you don't include any CDI, JSF, or jstl (I have no idea why you'd need that though, JSF 2 uses facelets by default) in your war, they're already provided for you by the container.

In short, don't bundle any spec jars, or spec implementation jars in your war unless you're using jetty or plain tomcat.

Comment: Great, I built project with Maven and specified, that all libs are provided by the container and it works now. Thank you!